# How to remove mysql-server-core-5.5 even if it has dependencies?

Tags: server, mysql, client, akonadi

I am trying a clean install of mysql so I tried uninstalling mysql-client and mysql-server. I can't seem to uninstall mysql-server-core-5.5 using `sudo dpkg --remove mysql-server-core-5.5` because of its dependency with akonadi.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of mysql-server-core-5.5:
 akonadi-backend-mysql depends on mysql-server-core-5.5.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server-core-5.5 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-core-5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$ apt-get purge --auto-remove mysql-server-core
...<output from apt-get>...
```

In general, you should use `apt-get` instead of `dpkg` directly to install/remove software on a Debian/Ubuntu.

For mysql, you might also want to follow the above up with this:

```
$ rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I tried that but this is the result `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-workspace-bin : Depends: plasma-desktop (= 4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                              plasma-netbook (= 4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                              plasma-active but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
`

Comment: This looks like you did something else with the packages. Maybe a forced removal of some package. Try `apt-get install -f` to fix that. Also, I think you down vote in this case is a little out of place since my answer would likely work if there weren't other problems with the packages on your system.

Comment: I just tried `apt-get install -f` and it still displays `The following packages have unmet dependencies: kde-workspace-bin : Depends: plasma-desktop (= 4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed or plasma-netbook (= 4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed or plasma-active but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

P.S. I didn't downvote you :/

Comment: Upvoted to compensate for somebody's completely inappropriate downvote.

Comment: I would definitely try the following `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade'. Maybe follow that with another `apt-get install -f`. If all that is unsuccessful, this may be a problem that I would need to see to fix. Also, I do see a reference to held packages, can you look over your /etc/apt/preferences* config to see if anything looks relevant? I don't have any apt preferences in my config, but that's where you'd configure package pins and other package trickery. Also, check for third party repos (like PPAs).

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

install `aptitude`

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then try remove with it

```
sudo aptitude remove mysql-server-core
```